# MFC Allow use to enable/disable floating toolbar via menu command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, docking

Added Update 2 on 3/29/2022

My MFC app has the menubar, toolbar, and status bar all working correctly. I am at the point I'm adding creature features...one that really annoys me is the choice of permanently locking them or allow them to float at runtime...I've looked high and low and I've yet to see an example where a user can allow this feature to be dynamically changed once the app is up and running. The first function is from the app which works correctly. NOTE: I have the items allowing docking commented out as this was my test code..I know that those are the lines that enable or disable docking at run time....-> // enable docking

```
    int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT pptCreate)
{
    CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerVS2005));
    if ( -1 == CMDIFrameWndEx::OnCreate(pptCreate) )
        return -1;

    // create menu bar
    if ( !m_wndMenuBar.Create(this) )
        return -1;  
    m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY);
    
    // prevent the menu bar from taking the focus on activation
    CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceMenuFocus(FALSE);
    
    // set the visual manager and style based on persisted value
    theApp.m_nAppLook = theApp.GetInt(_T("ApplicationLook"), ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_VS_2008);
    OnApplicationLook(theApp.m_nAppLook);

    // create tool bar
    if ( !m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|CBRS_TOP|CBRS_GRIPPER|CBRS_TOOLTIPS|CBRS_FLYBY|CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) || !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME) )
        return -1;

    // create status bar
    if ( !m_wndStatusBar.Create(this) || !m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(miIndicators, sizeof(miIndicators)/sizeof(UINT)) )
        return -1;

    // enable docking
    //m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    //m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndToolBar.EnableToolTips(TRUE);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
    DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);

    // enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window behavior
    CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);
    // enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window auto-hide behavior
    EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

    // create docking windows
    if (!CreateDockingWindows())
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create docking windows\n");
        return -1;
    }

    m_wndOutput.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndOutput);

    return 0;
}
```

So I've created a menu item that toggles a flag to turn "docking" on and off. The variable switches correctly.. but the command execution of turning the dock "3 dots" on the left side of the menubar and toolbar always remain...i.e. never goes from Float to Dock mode and vice versa. The logic of the toggle works as I can see in my debugging status window the entry points of TRUE and FALSE are seen each time I click the menu. So I guess the question is, can these items be dynamically turned from FLOAT to DOCK without destroying the window and trying to reinit it which would be a visual disaster?

```
void CMainFrame::UserDockingBarsOption()
{
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--CMainFrame::UserDockingBarsOption()"));

    if (UserDockingFlag == TRUE)

    {   
        m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
        m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
        EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
        UserDockingFlag = FALSE;
        pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--Inside True"));
    }
    else
    {
        m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(FALSE);
        m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(FALSE);
        EnableDocking(FALSE);
        UserDockingFlag = TRUE;
        pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--Inside False"));
    }
}
```

## Update 1:

So like my other posts, I'm back after a family matter. I revisited this and because I'm using:

```
CMFCMenuBar m_wndMenuBar;
CMFCToolBar m_wndToolBar;
```

and the only member I can find is `IsFloat` as a question, not an execute. So it was mentioned I can float or dock it via:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/docking-and-floating-toolbars?view=msvc-160

Every example that I see is done within the `OnCreate` which does not help me as I can't recall it after it's already the child is already constructed. So my thought was to invalidate the toolbar, destroy the toolbar, recreate the tool bar with the user switch of dock or float, and then reorganize the toolbars. I have "most" of this working except for the actual switch control aspect to rebuild the menu with the user option of floating the toolbar or docking it.

What I did in my property sheet is created two buttons for two seperate functions to see if I can get each piece of this to work. One button is `destroy` the toolbar, the other button is `create` i.e. recreate the toobar....and both of those "work".

This is all being done in the MainFrame.cpp for simplicity of the member variables, I may move it later if I can get it working.

There are the two functions:

Destroy Function:

```
void CMainFrame::OnToolBarDestroy()
{
    
    m_wndToolBar.Invalidate();
    m_wndToolBar.DestroyWindow();
    RecalcLayout();
    //OnToolBarCreate();

    //m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); // Hide toolbar
}
```

Recreate Toolbar outside of `OnCreate`

```
    int CMainFrame::OnToolBarCreate()
{
    // TODO: Add your implementation code here.

    if (m_wndToolBar)
    {
        m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("Error: Icon toolbar is already active, action cancelled"));
        m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--Error: Icon toolbar is already active, action cancelled"));
        return -1;
    }

    // Create ToolBar toolbar
    if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
        | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to Create Dialog ToolBar\n");
        return -1;
    }

    CRect rcClientOld;
    CRect rcClientNew;

    GetClientRect(rcClientOld);
    RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0, reposQuery, rcClientNew);

    //m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    //DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);

    RecalcLayout();
    //m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE); // Show toolbar
    return -1;

}
```

So what is commented out that would make it "work" assuming following the `OnCreate` code order up to this point:

`//m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);`

`//DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);`

What happening is the successful destroy, and successful rebuild of the menu.

What I need for switch control is to either have the `line active` for `floating` or `commented out` for `docked` which I have also done in `OnCreate` but since this is for the rebuilt menu, I need this to follow that method switching in or out this line: `//m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);` ...but when I do....the toolbar gets all garbled up / missing all icons and I have to nuke the registry keys for the `workspace` to "try again"...

Any ideas on how I can make this work? I feel like I'm `This close` to getting it...I'm just unsure what I may be missing here to get across he goal line.

## Update 2

So I got the toolbar to come out of docked to float with modified code below without restarting the app. But there are issues, it seems to be drawing "ghost" bars underneath. If I double click the 3 dots, it will detach and the bar will float....GREAT! But, it leave a "mirror" behind....if I double click the floating menu, it redocks to the frame.

I know I'm close, I'm just missing a piece to finish this off. I've added the code below and a few screenshots of wha I'm seeing.....the point is I is "working", but I'm missing something...can anyone help?

OnDestroy method updated:

```
    int CMainFrame::OnToolBarDestroy()
{
    
    //if (!m_wndToolBar)
    //{
    //  m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("Error: Icon toolbar is already removed, action cancelled"));
    //  m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--Error: Icon toolbar is already removed, action cancelled"));
    //  return -1;
    //}

    //m_wndToolBar.Invalidate();
    //m_wndMenuBar.DestroyWindow();
    m_wndToolBar.DestroyWindow();
    //m_wndToolBar.AdjustDockingLayout();
    //RecalcLayout();
    //OnToolBarCreate();
    
    //return 0;

    CRect rcClientOld;
    CRect rcClientNew;
    GetClientRect(rcClientOld);
    RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0, reposQuery, rcClientNew);

    //m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE); // Hide toolbar
    RecalcLayout();
    return 0;
}
```

OnCreate method updated:

```
    int CMainFrame::OnToolBarCreate()
{
    enter code here// TODO: Add your implementation code here.

    if (m_wndToolBar)
    {
        m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("Error: Icon toolbar is already active, action cancelled"));
        m_wndOutput.AddStringDebugTab(_T("Debug: MainFrame--Error: Icon toolbar is already active, action cancelled"));
        return -1;
    }

    CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceMenuFocus(FALSE);
    //CMDIChildWndEx::m_bEnableFloatingBars = TRUE;

    // Create ToolBar toolbar
    if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_ALIGN_TOP
        | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to Create Dialog ToolBar\n");
        return -1;
    }


    m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(FALSE);
    m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(FALSE);
    m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
    DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
    //  DockPaneLeftOf(&m_wndToolBar);
    CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);
    EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

    CRect rcClientOld;
    CRect rcClientNew;
    GetClientRect(rcClientOld);
    RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0, reposQuery, rcClientNew);

    m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("I'm created 1 times"));

    //m_wndToolBar.ResetAll();

    RecalcLayout();

    //m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE); // Show toolbar
    return 0;

}
```

The images below:

1. Start from OnCreate with the panes properly "docked" mode
2. Destroyed ToolBar
3. ToolBar is switched from dock to float mode with Update 2 code. Ghost bars shown in the image. Trying to solve that issue.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Soooooo....anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this riddle?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Could you describe your needs in detail? What does "without destroying the window" mean? If you could provide a minimal example, it will help solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this link will work: https://codejock.com/assets/images/support/articles/mfc/commandbars/tutorial3.gif but if you look at each toolbar, on the left are the 3 dots...that means you can grab them and move them and undock etc. I'm trying to figure out how to choose between locking them or allowing them to float by the users choice. By destroying the window, I mean, if I were to try and "reinit" the boot code with a switch that says docked/not docked...I would have to destroy the window and redraw it with the new settings...I "think" that would be visually not good.

Comment: Does this article help? https://help.perforce.com/stingray/12.2/Stingray_Studio_HTML_User_Guide/index.html#page/Stingray%20Studio/otug-dockingwindows.066.04.html

Comment: I saw that a while back, but if I am reading it right, that is to hide and unhide the toolbar...I am simply looking to "lock" or dock vs float the control without having to redraw it.

Comment: Sounds to me that docking and undocking is already possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/docking-and-floating-toolbars?view=msvc-160

Comment: Yes, I know and understand that it possible. My post is about how to do it on the fly. The line:  //m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY); at run time will allow docking or if commented, no docking, but it's done at the window creation time. I am looking to see if I can do it after the program is up and running as a creature feature option. I guess maybe a registry entry on app startup might suffice now that I think about it....but would still be a nice to have upon a menu selection without restart of the app.

Comment: But I thought a user can drag a toolbar into the dock and drag it out on demand anyway.

Comment: Well if I comment out those lines for docking enable, and then start the app, they are perma sealed to the mainframe. So that is why I thought it might be a neat creature feature...I sometimes found myself undocking when I didn't want to....but other times...was ease of use to move them out of the way.....so giving the user that flexibility is what I'm after.

Comment: I have circled back to this, I'm still unclear on how to do this because all the methods I've seen are during `OnCreate`. Are there any examples where this can be done dynamically and then redraw the toolbars without having to restart the app?

Comment: I've added Update 1 with a few questions and thoughts on my new methodology....any thoughts?